# How do I get twitter/friendfeed like home urls in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url

I want to be able to have twitter like friendly urls like http://twitter.com/username. How to pull this off in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to have a catch-all route at the bottom of your routing table. Something like:

```
map.connect '/:slug', :controller => 'users', :action => 'show'
```

Then in the users controller....

```
def show
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:slug])
end
```

I would also recommend catching a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` to show a 404 page. You can put something like this in `ApplicationController`:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :not_found
```

then define a method `not_found` to render an error page or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Comment: Its cool. However I was looking for something that does not expose the controller. Like in the example given as part of question description.